# Why would one prefer POP3 over IMAP in outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, imap, pop3

I've seen 2 different experienced administrators - who don't know each other - configure Outlook for their customers to use POP3, even tough IMAP was available.

What are good reasons to use POP3 when setting up an Outlook user, if the email server provides IMAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With POP3 Outlook will delete email from the server after downloading so if the email server has limited space POP3 prevents the mailbox from filling up.

Another reason is if you have multiple email accounts, POP3 allows you to see all of the email in one Inbox instead of having to check multiple ones. This is the main reason I use POP3 since I have 8 email accounts.

There are also reasons to choose, or not choose, POP3 dependent on how a company works. Since POP3 fully downloads all the email to their computer, they will always have a copy, even if the account is deleted. I work at a real estate company where the agents need to save a copy of their email even if they switch to a different company (for both legal and marketing reasons). If they used IMAP they could lose all the email. OTOH, in most company environments this could be a liability so they would use IMAP.

Lastly, in Outlook 2007 and older, IMAP only downloads headers by default while POP3 has everything local so searching email is faster and, with multiple accounts, much easier.

Comment: Turns out there was also another reason: If the email host deletes the emails for any reason (e.g. lack of competence), the admin will get blamed, even if they have no control over the server/host.